# How to fix a Fatal Error

Tags: magento-1.7, fatal-error, image-upload

I have Magento 1.7.  My customers have recently been receiving this error message when trying to upload photos to our site.  We use a FTP to hold our pictures.  I was wondering if anyone can assist with what to do about the following error.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 7680 bytes) in
>   /home1/photofet/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php
>   on line 674

Thanks for any assistance you can give us!

Comment: In 1.7, at the line 674 there is only a method definition. https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php#L674. This should not result in memory issues. Make sure your core is not modified. You can post lines 670 to 680 from your file in the question

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the PHP memory limit. You can do this by either editing the *.htaccess* file in the Magento installation folder, or by editing the php.ini configuration file for your web server i.e. for Ubuntu this is in */etc/php5/apache2/php.ini*

I don't know how much RAM your server has, but you could try:

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP memory limit is set to 256MB which is absolute minimum to run Magento and still most of time throws errors like this one. Increase memory limit to 512MB or even more and this problem should go away.